# Try to connect via RDP to Windows Azure

Tags: windows, azure, rdp

I initially thought I was so silly to have forgot the password immediately after I created it, but after some attempts I'm still not able to get it through the Windows Azure VM.

Although I changed the endpoint, checked everything I can, the RDP on my mac keep saying "Try reconnecting to the Windows-based computer or contact the administrator".

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article - [Moving a Windows Azure Virtual Machine from one Virtual Network to Another](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walterm/archive/2013/05/29/moving-a-virtual-machine-from-one-virtual-network-to-another.aspx) - it describes how to move drives from one VM to another.  Just create another VM and use the old drives to the new one.